"Setup failed - Unknown error" starting a new bulk data export from Google Search Console to BigQuery
I’m trying to set up bulk data export from Google Search Console to BigQuery, using Google’s guide here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/12917675?hl=en.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Created a new project in Google Cloud Console, enabled BigQuery, and gave Search Console the necessary permissions.
Went to the bulk data export settings in Search Console (https://search.google.com/search-console/settings/bulk-data-export) and filled in:


Cloud project ID: Pasted the project ID from the Google Cloud
project.
Dataset name: Used "searchconsole" and tried other suffixes
too.
Dataset location: Selected "United States (US)" and tried other
regions.

When I hit "Continue," I get this error: *Setup failed. Issue: Unknown error. Learn more (linked here to https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/12919198?hl=en#errors).
The help article mentions: “Export failed for an unknown reason. Wait for the next scheduled export to see if this issue has been resolved.”
I’ve waited and retried but keep hitting the same issue. Any suggestions on what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Yes, you seemed to have the correct setup in your GSC to BigQuery for the bulk export. The Unknown error failed for unknown reasons, all you need to do is to retry for another export and revisit your setup and check the following:

Check again the IAM permission, it should have the editor and owner permission, then it should ask you to grant the permission. GCS and BQ should have the correct permissions and roles

Check your dataset, your dataset seems to be okay

Dataset location seems to be okay also


If issues still persist, you can reach out to Google Cloud Support to deeply investigate your account and provide guidance.

You can add specifics, The answer you provided is general suggestions.
